# How to force ui-datepicker date format to ("yyyy-MM-dd")

Tags: asp.net-core, date, model-view-controller, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can someone please help me with formatting a date in a form-control ui-datepicker.  Despite setting the format in the model and in the view the picker ignores that and uses MM/dd/yyyy.

In the model I have:

```
public DateTime InvoiceUtc { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    private DateTime _SetDefaultInvoiceUtc = DateTime.Now;

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime UserDefaultInvoiceUtc
    {
        get
        {
            return _SetDefaultInvoiceUtc;
        }
        set
        {
            InvoiceUtc = value;
        }
    }
```

And in the view I have the following:

```
<input asp-for="InvoiceUtc" class="form-control ui-datepicker" type="date" placeholder="Start Date" required value="@Model.UserDefaultInvoiceUtc.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
```

But the date appears in MM/dd/yyyy format which isn't used anywhere in any model in the entire application. In fact I have never even seen that date format anywhere ever!!  Any clues anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna show Date in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd`, You can refer to this simple demo:

```
public class DateTest
    {
        public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datepicker'>
     <input asp-for="MyDate" type="text"  class="form-control" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#MyDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
    });
</script>
```

**Gif Demo**

[image]